# how to make the user always come back to the part where it stopped

Tags: laravel

I'm doing a site based on learning courses with laravel and I would like every time the user comes back on the course it directs on the page to which he stopped. An idea of ​​how I can proceed?

Comment: You can save the last visited page on the database.

Comment: Share the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `last visited url` on database. Then, when the user log in, just retrive that url and redirect the user to that page.

Some code to demonstrate:

Create a migration to add `last_visited_page` to the existing users table:

> php artisan make:migration add_last_visited_page_to_users

```php
//Add last visited page to users table:
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->string('last_visited_url')->nullable();
});
```

To store the last url to the database, you can add an update routine to your controllers function, like this:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    //The show function code
    //Before the return, add:
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->last_visited_url = Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
    $user->save();
}
```

Now, you need to change the default `authenticated` function. Inside `LoginController`,
by default at `app\Http\Controllers\Auth` directory:

```php
public function authenticated()
{
    $userLastVisitedUrl = Auth::user()->last_visited_url;
    if (!is_null($userLastVisitedUrl))
        return redirect($userLastVisitedUrl);
    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```

Now, whenever a user got logged in to your system, will be redirected to the last page visited;

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution will probably look like this one.

Comment: I have updated my code. Take a look at the answer again.

Comment: Ok. I'm waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

We can use laravel `URL::previous()`

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ URL::previous() }}">back</a>
```